# Minecraft Bedrock Edition 1.14.6 - Test for specific potion type

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing on bedrock edition, so afaik I do not have the ability to look at NBT tags. I am trying to create a puzzle where the player must brew a specific potion in order to unlock a door. Is there a way to test for a specific potion? I don't mind how the testing is done, i.e. they could need to place it in a hopper, a chest, an item frame, drink it, simply brew it, etc. I can't seem to find any method that would work, the commands in bedrock seem very limited.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there's no NBT, there are [data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Bedrock_Edition) for different types of potions.

You can use [`clear`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/clear) in a repeating command block to clear all the potions of a particular type and use a comparator to unlock the door.

Put this in a repeating command block:

```
clear @a potion <data value>
```

where the `<data value>` is one of the following (from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Bedrock_Edition)):

```
┌─────────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│           Potion            │ Regular │ Extended │ Enhanced │
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ Water Bottle                │       0 │          │          │
│ Mundane Potion              │       1 │        2 │          │
│ Thick Potion                │       3 │          │          │
│ Awkward Potion              │       4 │          │          │
│ Potion of Night Vision      │       5 │        6 │          │
│ Potion of Invisibility      │       7 │        8 │          │
│ Potion of Leaping           │       9 │       10 │       11 │
│ Potion of Fire Resistance   │      12 │       13 │          │
│ Potion of Swiftness         │      14 │       15 │       16 │
│ Potion of Slowness          │      17 │       18 │          │
│ Potion of Water Breathing   │      19 │       20 │          │
│ Potion of Healing           │      21 │          │       22 │
│ Potion of Harming           │      23 │          │       24 │
│ Potion of Poison            │      25 │       26 │       27 │
│ Potion of Regeneration      │      28 │       29 │       30 │
│ Potion of Strength          │      31 │       32 │       33 │
│ Potion of Weakness          │      34 │       35 │          │
│ Potion of Decay             │      36 │          │          │
│ Potion of the Turtle Master │      37 │       38 │       39 │
│ Potion of Slow Falling      │      40 │       41 │          │
└─────────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

<sup>sorry mobile users</sup>

Then put a redstone comparator next to it, which will output a signal strength equal to the number of items removed.